# I have a simple binary tree and I am trying find the last node of the tree

Tags: python, data-structures

findlast func is returning the correct node (checked the value before returning) but the receiving node named lastnode becomes none

simply returning the last node of the tree to later substitute the node to be deleted with this one

```
class tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None 

    def findlast(self,node,arr):
        if(node.left!=None):
            arr.append(node.left)
        if(node.right!=None):
            arr.append(node.right)
        if(len(arr)==1):
                print(arr[0].data)  #prints 3
                return arr[0]
        elif(self.root==None and len(arr)==0):
            print("empty tree")
        elif(self.root!=None and len(arr)==0):
            return self.root
        else:
            self.findlast(arr.pop(0),arr)


class treeNode:

    def __init__(self,data=None,left=None,right=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right 

bst=tree()
tn1=treeNode(2)
tn2=treeNode(3)
bst.root=treeNode(1,tn1,tn2)
arr=list()
print(bst.findlast(bst.root,arr).data)   #throws error "nonetype has no object data"
```

Comment: How do  you define what the "last node" is?

Comment: I am sorry, I had originally defined last node as the receiver argument to the function. like below
lastnode=bst.findlast(bst.root,arr)

Comment: I meant, what do you consider to be the last node of the tree? For example, the one at the deepest level, the right-most, or some other criteria?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Jim. I consider the last node to be the rightmost node at the deepest level.

Comment: actually, I have not assigned the node with value '1' to the root of the tree. Regardless of this,the returning part is still a conundrum. Here is the modified code anyway

class tree:
    def __init__(self,node=None):
        self.root=node 

+==========================

tn1=treeNode(2)
tn2=treeNode(3)
bst=tree(treeNode(1,tn1,tn2))

+=======================

Answer (score 0):

To find the rightmost node at the lowest level, do an inorder traversal of the tree. When you find a leaf node, check its depth against the deepest node you've found previously. If the new node's depth is greater than or equal to the previous deepest node, then the new node becomes the deepest node. This works because an inorder traversal of the tree will visit the leaf nodes from left to right.

This is an O(n) operation. It's not possible to do it any faster because you must traverse the entire tree to find the deepest node.